# Loop the status Result using PowerShell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ebs, snapshot

I have written a script in PowerShell which creates aws ebs snapshot , its working fine without an issue , except i am not able get the Progress status at regular interval to proceed with next step in script. Until unless i dont get update that snapshot is 100% completed i cannot proceed with next step in my script which is upgrade of application. Any help is appreciated.

```
    Import-Module -name AWSPowerShell
    $CostIdValue = Read-Host "Please provide ID , e.g.:- 111"
    $CostId = Get-EC2Volume -profilename xyz -region us-east-2 | ? { $_.Tags.Count -gt 0 -and $_.Tags.Key -eq "CostId" -and $_.Tags.Value -eq $CostIdValue} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty VolumeId 
    $snapshot = New-EC2Snapshot -profilename xyz -region us-east-2 -VolumeId $CostId
    #$snapshotId = Get-EC2Volume -profilename xyz -region us-east-2 | ? { $_.Tags.Count -gt 0 -and $_.Tags.Key -eq "CostId" -and $_.Tags.Value -eq $CostIdValue} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SnapshotId
    $a = $snapshot.SnapshotId
    #Write-Output $a
    New-EC2Tag -profilename xyz -region us-east-2 -Resource $a -Tag @{ Key="CostId"; Value = $CostIdValue }
    
    $i = Get-EC2Snapshot -profilename xyz -region us-east-2 | ? { $_.Tags.Count -gt 0 -and $_.Tags.Key -eq "CostId" -and $_.Tags.Value -eq "$CostIdValue"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty State

for ($i = 1; $i -le 100; $i++ )
{
Write-Progress -Activity "Search in Progress" -Status "$i% Complete:" -PercentComplete $i;
}
```

Comment: [1] for you to get progress on something ... you need to be INSIDE that process [inside a loop, for instance]. your progress display is OUTSIDE the process. [*grin*] ///// [2] the progress cmdlet is SLOW ... so you will slow down your script somewhat if you use it. ///// [3] there does not seem to be anything in the snapshot process to monitor for showing progress. what can you use to show that something is happening?

Comment: Thanks.. I am looking to take the progress percentage , like it ping the snapshot kind of logic using get and print the status , as this script. will become part of application upgrade and application upgrade will only happen after snapshot becomes 100%..

Comment: in order to show progress ... you need to _detect it_. is there anything in the process that lets you know how much of the process has completed? i can't see any such thing when i read thru the docs.

Comment: As far as i know we dont have anything specific for that , so now i am thinking to create wait condition in script which will check every 5 mins and write the output which again is not standard way.

Comment: start the snapshot call in a PSJob and then call to it every few seconds from your main script. that can at least let you show a "something is still happening" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i used while and checked the status on continuous interval. Now script is checking the snapshot based upon status and its. working perfectly as expected. Thanks everyone for jumping in..

```
while ((Get-EC2Snapshot -profilename xyz -region $region | ? { $_.Tags.Count -gt 0 -and $_.Tags.Key -eq "CostId" -and $_.Tags.Value -eq "$CostIdValue"}).Status -ne "completed")
 {
       "Snapshot for db is $CostIdValue pending ..."
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    }
    
      "Snapshot for db is $CostIdValue completed ..."
```